# Entity framework code first table clean up

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I am using EF, code first. I have to clean up (delete *all* the records) from bunch of tables if it meets certain condition. I was thinking to create stored procedure with set of Truncate command. my questions are:

Question 1: is following SP correct? couple of tables are having one to may relationship.  Do I need to return any value, does truncate return any status, like success or failure? in other words is there a way i get confirmation that all tables are clean? FYI: each tables may have millions of records.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [CleanupTables]
AS
BEGIN

    Truncate table table1

    Truncate table table2

    Truncate table table3

    Truncate table table4

    Truncate table table5

    Truncate table table6

END
```

Question 2: I have entity class of these tables in my code. So is there any other way, other than calling SP I can delete all the records.

Question 3: how can i call stored procedure from EF, which doesn't return or take any input parameter. I saw bunch of example online but they all are having input parameters and output values.

Comment: I would specifically call the Schema to your tables for both clarity and to avoid any naming resolution problems. Also, Best practice says to name your proc in a way that distinguishes it. As your database might someday be large, proper naming helps. I prefer USP attached to the name.

Comment: i do have schema attached to my tables and also have proper name for my SP. what is USP?

Comment: Unfortunately, my experience is limited C# and EF, though an excellent article on the subject from [MSDN is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx) explains the different ways EF is designed to expand beyond PROCs. As for feedback, that depends. Again, I do not use EF, but I can tell you that SQL minimally logs the action as it dumps the entire table instead of row by row. Be aware of that. Use boleans to return feedback after running the commands. Example: `IF EXISTS(<QUERY>) SET @value = 1; returns @value`

Comment: User Stored Procedure. You may have seen the phrase UDF, which is also User Defined Function. Note that you should never use the prefix SP_ to your objects in SQL Server.

Comment: Last comment: your example given actually calls the Schema implicitly. This may be good now, but A) SQL runs an implicit naming resolution, and B) if those tables ever change it may be problematic. Eh, it is minimal, but it it is worth explicitly writing the Schema. `dbo.tableA` to make the code more durable. Hope the link helps!

Comment: @clifton_h Thanks. appreciate  your help.